# Neatest way to organize commands in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a program in Qt 5.1 C++ that is going to communicate with an Arduino board via a list of commands. These commands should preferably be stored in ascii code or easily converted to that.

I wish the commands to be something like the pseudo code below, both when it comes to initialization and declaration, and also be inherently typesafe

```
commandlist consisting of strings:
{
   get = "1",  //Ascii 1
   set = "0"
etc
}
```

and be accessed by something like

```
sendcommand(commandlist.get) etc
```

I know there are many ways to do this, but which is the neatest? An enum class? Some special function in Qt? A namespace with all commands defined as variables?

I was thinking about a static class with static variables as commands but that's all but neat when the initializing has to be done.

Comment: use enums not strings, and perhaps a map that does map those enums to strings.

Comment: You can do a small embedded DSL (domain-specific language) using template expressions :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [strongly-typed enum](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html), in combination with a string array (or vector):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
enum class CommandType
{
  Get = 0,
  Set,       // this will be set to 1, etc...
  ...
};

// ...

const std::vector<std::string> commandNames = {"get", "set", ...};

// ...

CommandType cmd = CommandType::Get;
auto commandName = commandNames[static_cast<int>(cmd)];
// use commandName here
```

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this:

```
class Command {
public:
    Command (QByteArray const& ascii) :ascii_(ascii) {}
    QByteArray ascii_;
};

static const Command cmd_get("1");
static const Command cmd_set("0");

sendCommand(cmd_get);
sendCommand(cmd_set);
```

If you don't plan on having dynamic command texts, you could just use a `const char*`.

EDIT actually it would probably be better having these as static class members:

```
class Command {
public:
    static const Command GET;
    static const Command SET;

    explicit Command (QByteArray const& ascii) :ascii_(ascii) {}
    QByteArray const& getAscii() const { return ascii_; }

private:
    QByteArray ascii_;
};

// Implementation
const Command Command::GET("1");
const Command Command::SET("0");

sendCommand(Command::GET);
sendCommand(Command::SET);
```

Also, since QByteArray uses implicit sharing, copies of the class are relatively cheap.